# Как легче создавать навигационные панели?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, frontend

Как будет правильнее всего: создать навигационные панели вручную, или с помощью bootstrap?

В навигационных панели имеется логотип слева, а вправа меню/ссылки и кнопка выход вместе с иконкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неужели для того, чтобы сверстать за несколько минут простую панель навигации, нужна целая библиотека набора инструментов?

Нужно запомнить одну простую вещь: кто начинает с Bootstrap, тот в итоге потом не умеет ничего. Ручками, всё нужно делать своими ручками.

```css
.header {
  display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; align-items: center;
  height: 50px; padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #fafafb; border-top: 3px solid #f48024; box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
}

.logo {
  width: 150px; height: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f); background-size: 100%;
}

.links {flex: 3 1 auto;}
.links ul {list-style: none;}
.links li {display: inline-block; margin: 0 10px;}

.out button {float: right;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="links">
    <ul>
      <li>Главная</li>
      <li>Вопросы</li>
      <li>Метки</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="out"><button>Выйти</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличная мотивация!