# Через margin-right при сдвиге в лево текст перебрасывается на следуйщую строку

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь подвинуть текст влево через `margin-top` как бы не пытался не получается оно просто перебрасывается на следующую строку чтобы не пытался делать.

Спасибо большое кто поможет.

```css
.headtext {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="Img/Logo.png" alt="" width="40" height="40" class="logo">
  <span class="logo-text">PolitWar</span>
  <span class="headtext" class="rp">Правила РП</span>
  <a class="headtext" href="">Карта</a>
  <a class="headtext" href="">Discord Сервер</a>
  <a class="headtext" href="">Вконтакте</a>
  <a class="headtext" href="">Характеристики Государств</a>
  <a class="headtext" href="h">Донат</a>
</header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _"... текст влево через margin-top"_ ??? 0_o

Comment: ```margin-right: 0px;```

Comment: Это что - `<span class="headtext" class="rp">` ?

Comment: Это спан с классом там чисто для текста стили

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую почитать о [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) и пересмотреть свою вёрстку, если требуется сделать как на скрине в ответе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header__left {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header__logo {
  display: block;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__right {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.header__link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__link:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1ch;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="Img/Logo.png" class="header__logo">
    <span class="header__logo-text">PolitWar</span>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <span class="header__link rp">Правила РП</span>
    <a class="header__link" href="#">Карта</a>
    <a class="header__link" href="#">Discord Сервер</a>
    <a class="header__link" href="#">Вконтакте</a>
    <a class="header__link" href="#">Характеристики Государств</a>
    <a class="header__link" href="#">Донат</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Во flex вроде вместо width flex-grow используется)

Comment: Впервые слышу, чтобы `flex-grow` заменял `width`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, flex-basis

Comment: Почитал доку, сомнительное свойство, в любом случае первым делом смотрит `width` или `height`, на практике обходился без него всегда. Так, что даже не знаю, что вам ответить.

Comment: Я где-то читал, что с width могут быть проблемы, поэтому предпочтительнее flex-basis. Сейчас попробую найти в каких ситуациях.

Answer (score 2):

`margin-top` - отступ сверху.
`headtext` - это ссылки
Им (т.е. `<a>`) надо указывать `width:100%, height` чтобы кликать было удобно, как я помню.
А вам не проще сделать

```html
<ul><li><a class="headtext" href="">Карта</a></li></ul>
```

Ссылки меню в ul а logo отдельно img
Или нужное взять в `<div>` задать ему ширину и двигать его.
И, вы `header` двигаете? А он наверное `width:100%` или нет, обычно занимает всю просматриваемую область?
А классы через пробел ставятся.

```
class="headtext rp"
```

Comment: _"А классы через запятую ставятся. `class="headtext, rp"`"_ Ох... рукалицо...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да я двигаю его через ```header``` и у меня width и height вообще не установлены насчет класса я ошибся я случайно написал класс заместо айди для кода js

Comment: И классы ставятся через пробел как я помню ```class="Headtext rp"```

Comment: Да, через пробел, прошу прощения.

Comment: Посмотрите вашу страницу в браузере через Просмотр кода в chrom или мозиле -> исследовать элемент. Там же протестируйте, а если .headtext{margin-left:50px;}

Comment: Я добавил картинку где видно что происходит при сдвиге

Comment: Через див желательно сделать

Comment: @Half: желательно делать через _flex_

Comment: @UModeL Можете пожайлуста показать пример?

Comment: @Half: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239177/265406

Answer (score 2):

> Пытаюсь подвинуть текст влево через `margin-top`

Это отсуп сверху, он вам текст подвинет вниз. Вам нужно свойство `margin-right`

> как бы не пытался не получается оно просто перебрасывается на
> следующую строку

Попробуйте `text-wrap: no-wrap` назначить, а еще ссылкам нужен `display: inline-block`

Но я бы использовал [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) для верстки меню.